# Ruby on Rails Tuto <% if signed_in? %> error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#code-layout_signin_signout_links) but I don't understand why i'm having an error on `<% if signed_in? %>` (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)

Here is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

And my sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token  = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
end
```

Am I missing something obvious ? I get those errors :

```
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1005071352_28922208'
```

**EDIT** :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.remember_token: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
```

Thanks

Comment: is this all you see in your logs?  if not, can you show the whole log?

Comment: Oh you are right and it was right in front of me :    `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.remember_token: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1`     I performed `bundle exec rake db:migrate` then `bundle exec rake test:prepare`

Comment: Looks like you haven't run the migration, or restarted the server. Try rake db:migrate first and execute this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I missed one step of the tutorial. I did not realized that my migration what empty when I performed `rails generate migration add_remember_token_to_users` :

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

I just follow [the advice](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#code-add_remember_token_to_users) and perform a new migration (because of the timestamp) :

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

Thanks all for your help